# Force ArcCatalog to refresh TreeView and View after programmatically creating a table

Tags: arcobjects

I'm programmatically creating a table in a geodatabase and am trying to force ArcCatalog to refresh the display to show the new table.  I've tried the following which does not work:

```
Dim gxApp As IGxApplication = TryCast(m_application, IGxApplication)
... 'Create table here

'Then trying to force tree view to show new table...
gxApp.Refresh(0)

'And trying to force view to display...
gxApp.View.Refresh()
```

Missing something simple here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling [IGxObject.Refresh](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Refresh_Method/00140000016t000000/) for the object corresponding to the [IGxDatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0014000000t2000000) which holds the table.