# ArcCatalog tree not refreshing after adding new custom IGxObject at runtime

Tags: arcobjects, .net, arccatalog

I am using ArcObjects 10.1 (.NET) to customize ArcCatalog: adding new nodes in catalog tree like in the [Esri's example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Custom_Root_Object_Style_Gallery/000100000p6z000000/). But when I add new child node to already expanded parent, it doesn't show up in tree. Actually, catalog tree node never updates again after being expanded.

Any solutions?

Tried the answer to [Force ArcCatalog to refresh TreeView and View after programmatically creating a table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8004/), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I developed the following code that would refresh the Folder Connection in the Catalog window in ArcMap which may help.

```vb
' Refresh Catalog Window (if open)
Dim pDockableWindowManager As IDockableWindowManager
pDockableWindowManager = My.ArcMap.DockableWindowManager

Dim sUID As UID
sUID = New UID
sUID.Value = "{7F09BEFF-4F85-48A2-A3DC-39430262799E}" 'GxBrowserDockWindow

Dim pDockableWindow As IDockableWindow
pDockableWindow = pDockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(sUID)

If pDockableWindow.IsVisible Then
    ' Get Browser
    Dim pGXBrowser As IGxBrowser
    pGXBrowser = pDockableWindow.UserData

    ' Get the Catalog
    Dim pGXCatalog As IGxCatalog
    pGXCatalog = pGXBrowser.InternalCatalog

    ' QI Catalog into GXObject
     Dim pGXObject As IGxObject
    pGXObject = DirectCast(pGXCatalog, IGxObject)

     ' QI GxObject into GxObjectContainer
     Dim pGxObjectContainer As IGxObjectContainer
     pGxObjectContainer = DirectCast(pGXObject, IGxObjectContainer)

     ' Get Gxobjects as an enumerate
     Dim pEnumGxObject As IEnumGxObject
     pEnumGxObject = pGxObjectContainer.Children

     ' Cycle through objects until we find the Folder Connections, then break out of loop
     Dim pGxObject2 As IGxObject
     pGxObject2 = pEnumGxObject.Next
     Do While Not pGxObject2 Is Nothing
        If TypeOf pGxObject2 Is IGxFolderConnections Then
           Exit Do
        End If
        pGxObject2 = pEnumGxObject.Next
     Loop

     ' Re-point GxObjectContainer to folder connection GxObject and refresh all
     pGxObjectContainer = DirectCast(pGxObject2, IGxObjectContainer)
     pEnumGxObject = pGxObjectContainer.Children
     pGxObject2 = pEnumGxObject.Next
     Do While Not pGxObject2 Is Nothing
          pGxObject2.Refresh()
          pGxObject2 = pEnumGxObject.Next
     Loop
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

In Refresh method just call ObjectRefreshed(...) on the IGxCatalog object that you got with the Attach method.

```
private IGxCatalog _catalog;
// ...
public void Attach(..., IGxCatalog pCatalog)
{
    // ...
    _catalog = pCatalog;
    // ...
}
// ...
public void Refresh()
{
    // ...
    _catalog.ObjectRefreshed(this);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arccatalog tree doesn't refresh on it's own. Right click on the added tree item and select refresh.

Comment: My custom tree nodes don't have context menus. But it is possible to force refresh by pressing F5 on the node (checked in debug). After that tree is not refreshed, but on the tab "Contents" everything is ok. See my screenshots and code in the [ArcGIS forum post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/80543-.NET-ArcCatalog-10.1-tree-doesn-t-refresh-after-adding-new-custom-IGxObject).